# Update the value of a row which is present in one of two tables

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have two tables

```
**Table A**

ID      Name   
 1       abc   
 2       bcd
 4       lmh 

**Table B** 

ID      Name   
 3       abc   
 5       bcd
```

I don't know in which table ID=4 resides so I want to update the value with ID=4 
how can i update the row with this?

I use UNION for selecting the value from multiple colmns but union is not working on update query.
I am using mysql.
 Please help.

Comment: Why don't you know?

Comment: Because it's selecting the value from two tables while i want to edit the row. And i dont know which table contain this value.

Comment: But why not just have one table?

Comment: because we have one different column for two different users in these two tables

Comment: just run the query twice. Once on each table. There can be no harm.

Comment: just did that :D

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's the good solution but I just run the update query two times. if it'll find some data with the requested id in either of tables it'll update the data